# React - how to have data added from above instead of below

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to have added be displayed from above, but it's getting submitted from bottom to up instead. Any feedback welcome.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div >
            <h1>Help items list</h1>
            <Table>
                <TH>
                    <TD>Title</TD>
                    <TD>Description</TD>
                </TH>
                {this.state.helpItems.map((child, index) => {
                    // console.log(child)
                    return <TR key={index}>
                        <TD>
                            {child.locale_content.da.help_title}
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            {child.locale_content.da.help_description}
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                }
                )}
            </Table>

            <Button
                label={'Create New'}
                onClick={this.props.handleNew}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could please elaborate `getting submitted from bottom to up instead `

Comment: Explain with `What you are trying, What you are getting output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flip the order your `this.state.helpItems` `array` is printed, you can either:

A. Push new `helpItems` to `this.state.helpItems` in an [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) esque manner:

```
this.setState({helpItems: [newItem, ...this.state.helpItems]})
```

or

B. `render()` `this.state.helpItems` in [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
this.state.helpItems.reverse().map(() => ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({helpItems: [newItem, ...this.state.helpItems]})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.